# node vs nodejs on Ubuntu package manager

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs

I would like to install node.js on my Ubuntu 14.04. However, there are two packages available: `node` and `nodejs`.

After some digging, I know that there used to be a package by the name of `node`. It is actually [Amateur Packet Radio Node Program](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/node/). This package was later renamed from `node` to `ax25-node`.

So, that leaves the confusing question: What is the difference between `node` (current) and `nodejs`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After some more digging, follwoing information should be useful for people who may have the same confusion as I did.

I managed to find that the [node](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/node) package in [Package repo of 14.04](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/allpackages). It turns out that `node` is still `Amateur Packet Radio Node Program`. (It's the historical versions before renamed to `ax25-node`)

However, just to make things even more confusing: after `sudo apt-get install nodejs` or `sudo apt-get install node`, you can execute `node -v`either way.

But `sudo apt-get install node` gives you a totally different program (which is not nodejs).

**Conclusion**: `sudo apt-get install nodejs` installs nodejs into `/usr/bin/` on Ubuntu.

PS:
The reason why after installing nodejs, you can do `node -v` is because in `/usr/bin/`, `node -> nodejs*`

Comment: My case node -v and nodejs -v shows defferent version !

Comment: @bowen when i use node -v i am getting The program node is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy

Comment: Please mark you answer as accepted. I guess it kind of answers the problem?